# How to check if Array of dates fall under current week

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to generate an Array of dates for current week.

Then i'm getting an Array of dates from system, now i want to check if any of these dates match against the Moment.js created current week.

If yes, then i would like to return their values( 0,1,2..  so i can manipulate the dom objects accordingly. (Example: if the match returns Sunday and Tuesday of current week then i would highlight them)

I've only gone so far it getting a single hard coded value to return true or false if the date falls under current week.

```
var REFERENCE = moment();
var startOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().startOf('week');

var endOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().endOf('week');
var highlightDays = ['2017-08-23','2017-08-25','2017-08-29']; //highlight respective days ONLY they fall under current week

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}


function isWithinThisWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isBetween(startOfWeek, endOfWeek);

}


console.log("is it within this week?  "+isWithinThisWeek(moment("2017-08-25")));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf8gkfca/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and moment [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to highlight the dates in the current week of the `highlightDays` array.

Using `dddd` token in [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) you will get `Sunday Monday ... Friday Saturday`, that are the values of your `data-day` attribute.

**EDIT:** The problem was the `isWithinThisWeek` method that gave wrong result for Sunday, because, as [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) states:

> Check if a moment is between two other moments, optionally looking at unit scale (minutes, hours, days, etc). **The match is exclusive.**

Then you can use both:

- [`isBetween(moment-like, moment-like, String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) passing `[]` as forth argument to make it inclusive.
- [`isSame(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) passing week as granularity parameter

Here a live example:

```js
var REFERENCE = moment(); 
var startOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().startOf('week');
var endOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().endOf('week');
var highlightDays = ['2017-08-18','2017-08-19','2017-08-20','2017-08-21','2017-08-22','2017-08-23','2017-08-24','2017-08-25','2017-08-26']; //highlight respective days ONLY they fall under current week

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while ( day.isBefore(endOfWeek) ) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}

function isWithinThisWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isBetween(startOfWeek, endOfWeek, null, '[]');
    // return momentDate.isSame(REFERENCE, 'week')
}

for(var i=0; i<highlightDays.length; i++){
  var m = moment(highlightDays[i]);
    if( isWithinThisWeek(m) ){
    var dayName = m.format('dddd').toLowerCase();
    $("[data-day='"+dayName+"']").addClass("highlight");
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="sunday">Sunday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="monday">Monday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="tuesday">Tuesday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="wednesday">Wednesday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="thursday">Thursday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="friday">Friday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-day="saturday">Saturday</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My answer is similar to the two already posted but:

- I do not use the `numToDays` temp array
- I do not rely on the order of the elements in the HTML

Comment: I also don't use a numToDays Array ;-)

Comment: @hallleron sure, but you rely on the order of the elements in the HTML :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can not get Sunday to be highlighted.

Comment: @user366123 updated my answer, the problem was the `isWithinThisWeek` method.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks a lot for your assistance. Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Fixed the highlighting bug for Sunday. You had to `subtract` one day from `startOfWeek` in the `isBetween()` call.

I think this is what you want:

```js
var REFERENCE = moment(); 
var startOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().startOf('week');
var endOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().endOf('week');
var highlightDays = ['2017-08-20','2017-08-21','2017-08-22','2017-08-23','2017-08-24','2017-08-25','2017-08-26'];

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}

function isWithinThisWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isBetween(startOfWeek.subtract(1, 'd'), endOfWeek.add(1, 'd'));  
}

for(var i = 0; i < highlightDays.length; i++){
console.log(isWithinThisWeek(moment(highlightDays[i])));
  if(isWithinThisWeek(moment(highlightDays[i]))){
    var date_converted = new Date(highlightDays[i]);
    $(".table td:eq("+date_converted.getDay()+")").addClass("highlight");
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td data-day="sunday">Sunday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="monday">Monday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="tuesday">Tuesday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="wednesday">Wednesday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="thursday">Thursday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="friday">Friday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="saturday">Saturday</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

I added a `for()` loop at the end and check if the date is in current week by using your function. Using this I use `addClass()` to highlight the matching records.

Comment: This is great however, it only highlights days which is today or in future. It does not highlight past days even though they are still in current week.

Comment: It does, have a look, I added yesterday's date as 4 entry ... It works

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Really appreciate it. However, i'm not able to highlight all the days of the week... Perhaps a Moment.js week issue?

Comment: What days can't be highlighted?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance. Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are after. I added a foreach loop and a simple array of days to convert int to the day name. Then it selects the `td` based of the data-day and highlights it.

```js
var REFERENCE = moment(); 
var startOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().startOf('week');
var endOfWeek = REFERENCE.clone().endOf('week');
var highlightDays = ['2017-08-23','2017-08-25','2017-08-29']; //highlight respective days ONLY they fall under current week

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}


function isWithinThisWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isBetween(startOfWeek, endOfWeek);
}

var numToDays = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

highlightDays.forEach(function(element) {
  if(isWithinThisWeek(moment(element))){
   var date = moment(element);    
    var day = date.format("d");
    $("td[data-day='"+numToDays[day]+"']").addClass("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td data-day="sunday">Sunday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="monday">Monday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="tuesday">Tuesday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="wednesday">Wednesday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="thursday">Thursday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="friday">Friday</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td data-day="saturday">Saturday</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can not get Sunday to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident with Moment.js, but i'll give it a try with plain JS.
Maybe this helps.

```js
var highlightDays = ['2017-08-23','2017-08-25','2017-08-29']; //highlight respective days ONLY they fall under current week
var date= new Date(); //Today Date
var today = date.getDay(); //Today Day of the week Number
var dayMSec = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //a day in ms
var weekMSec = dayMSec * 7; // a week in ms

//Here i calculate the start of the week timestamp(Using dates the starting day will be Sunday). TS in in ms
var startWeekTS = date.getTime() - (dayMSec * today); 

highlightDays.forEach(function(val, index){
  if(isWithinThisWeek(val)){
    //just logging
    console.log(highlightDays[index] + ' is within this week');
  }
});


function isWithinThisWeek(date) {
    //generate a Date() from passed arg
    date = new Date(date);
    //getting the ts of the date
    var dateMSec = date.getTime();
    //subtracting start of the week ts and arg ts
    var tsDiff = dateMSec - startWeekTS;
    
    //if ts is between 0 and a week expressed in ms
    if( tsDiff >= 0  && tsDiff< weekMSec){
      //here we go
      return true;
    }
    
    //nope
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Even though i wanted to stick with moment.js i still appreciate your help.